# Benign ELF dataset

Tags: repository, elf

I'm working on IoT malware classification using machine learning, currently I have a dataset consists of 1137 malicious ELF samples and they support different CPU architectures (i.e. intel, MIPS, ARM, SPARC, Motorola). So now trying to find out a set of benign ELF samples in order to perform the classification. I found .deb, .bin, and .RPM but I don't think I can do the classification using them.
Also I found benign ELFs, but the problem majority of them are supporting ARM arch, with few samples support Intel. 
Can you please advise me whether I can proceed with analyzing the other file extensions, and if you are aware of ELF repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you please advise me whether I can proceed with analyzing the other file extensions, and if you are aware of ELF repositories.

You can *extract* ELF files from `.deb` and `.rpm` packages:

```
mkdir aa && dpkg -x foo.deb aa
mkdir bb && rpm2cpio bar.rpm | (cd bb; cpio -idm; )
```

Analyzing `.deb`s and `.rpm`s directly is likely to teach your classifier that anything that is ELF is malicious, and anything that is no ELF is not; which isn't a very useful classifier.

Comment: Thanks very helpful, but the 2nd command didn't work with me. The directory `bb` is empty

Comment: @Mohannad Did the second command produce any errors? I just verified that it works for me.

Comment: It generated lots of text on the terminal, not an error, seems content of the RPM file. But `bb` direcotry is still empty. 
The output wasn't like the `mkdir aa && dpkg -x foo.deb aa`, where there are contents have been extracted in `aa` directory